# Django Middleware Error

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to write a custom django middleware package by referring an example [here](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/18/how-to-create-a-custom-django-middleware.html):

```
from django.conf import settings

class StackOverflowMiddleware(object):
    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        if settings.DEBUG:
            print exception.__class__.__name__
            print exception.message
        return None
```

and this is present at location `venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_error_assist/middleware.py`

I try to invoke/include this middleware in my django settings as follows:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django_error_assist.middleware.StackOverflowMiddleware', ]
```

But I get a traceback which I've been struggling to get rid of which follows like this :

```
File "/Users/Shyam/PycharmProjects/untitled/untitled/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/Users/Shyam/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application
    return WSGIHandler()
  File "/Users/Shyam/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 151, in __init__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "/Users/Shyam/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 82, in load_middleware
    mw_instance = middleware(handler)
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

Where am I going wrong ? Any leads/help will be appreciated. I'm trying to make this middleware a pip package.

I also did my homework of looking into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27438498/error-with-django-middleware), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43340811/django-middleware-error-middleware-changed-for-1-7) and of course the official django [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/middleware/) but couldn't get much help from these as in where am I going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Django from version 1.10 Middleware must accept `get_response` agrument, see [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/middleware/#init-get-response). Change your class to this:

```
class StackOverflowMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response

    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        if settings.DEBUG:
            print exception.__class__.__name__
            print exception.message
        return None
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to change all classes that took `object` to `MiddlewareMixin`.

```
class StackOverflowMiddleware(object):
    ....
```

to:

```
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin

class StackOverflowMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    ....
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. I tried the other answer and it worked.